# Do I need to use this many indexes in my SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, indexing

I'd appreciate some advice from SQL Server gurus here. Let me explain...

I have an SQL Server 2008 database table that has 21 columns. Here's a quick type of those:

- INT Primary Key
- Several other INT's that are indexes already (used to reference this and other tables)
- Several NVARCHAR(64) to hold user-provided text
- Several NVARCHAR(256) to hold longer user-provided text
- Several DATETIME2
- One BIGINT
- Several UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, one is already an index

The way this table is used is that it is presented to a user as a sortable table and a user can choose which column to sort it by. This table may contain many thousands of records (like currently it does 21,000 and it will be growing.)

So my question is, do I need to set each column as an INDEX to enable faster sorting?

PS. Forgot to say. The output obviously supports pagination, so the user sees no more than 100 rows at once.

Comment: The load is not very high. But what would I lose if I create all those indexes?

Comment: It depends on your query workload.... and your read to write ratio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, just having an index on a column does **not guarantee** that any queries will be any faster!

If you constantly use `SELECT *..` from that table, these non-clustered indices on a single column will most likely **not be used at all**.

A good nonclustered index is a **covering index**, which means, it contains all the necessary columns to satisfy one or multiple given queries. If you have this situation, then a nonclustered index can make sense - otherwise, in more cases than not, the nonclustered index is likely to be ignored by the query optimizer. The reason for this being: if you need all the columns anyway, the query would have to do **key lookups** from the nonclustered index into the actual data (the clustered index) for each row found - and the key lookup is a very expensive operation, so doing this for a lots of hits becomes overly costly, and the query optimizer will rather quickly switch to a index scan (possibly the clustered index scan) to fetch the data.

**Don't over-index** - use a well-designed clustered index, put indices on the foreign key columns to speed up joins - and then let it be for the time being. Observe your system, measure performance, *maybe* add an index here or there - but don't just overload the system with tons of indices!

Having too many indices can be worse than having none - every index must be maintained, e.g. updated for each `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statement - does that take time!

Comment: I think in `SQL Server 2008` behavior of the `*` operator is different and in execution plan I have been seen it `SQL Server 2008` use indexes.is it true?

Comment: @Kerezo: no, the behavior of `SELECT *` has not changed - in what way should it have?? If you ask for **all the columns** - the query must fetch that data from the clustered index (which **is** the data, in the leaf level). No other way to do it.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the explanation. It is only if I understood this clustered vs. nonclustered indexes terminology. Is there a simple explanations for these somewhere?

Comment: @marc_s I setup a table with a `PK` and a `Non-Clustered index` on a column. I use `Select *` and a `Where` clause on `Non-Clustered index column` and in execution plan I see query use the `Non-Clustered index`

Comment: @Kerezo: yes - maybe - but if you have a `SELECT *`, I'm betting you **also** see a **key lookup** - right?? I'm also just saying: quite quickly, if you have more than just two or three rows, the cost of doing all those key lookups will become too much for the query optimizer and it will switch to a clustered index scan. The key lookups are fine for **small numbers** of rows - 5, 10, 20 - depends on the table and loads of other factors. But quite quickly, the query optimizer will use a scan instead - since the key lookups are so expensive to do.

Comment: @ahmd0: see [SQL Server Index Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/) for starters.

Answer (score 2):

> this table is ... presented to a user as a sortable table ... [that] may contain many thousands of records

If you're ordering many thousands of records for display, you're doing it wrong. Typical users can reasonably process at most around 500 typical records. Exceptional users can handle a couple thousand. Any more than that, and **you're misleading your users** into a false sense that they've seen a representative sample.  This results in poor decision making and inefficient user workflow. Instead, you need to focus on a good search algorithm.

Another to keep in mind here is that more indexes means slower inserts and updates. It's a balancing act. Sql Server keeps statistics on what queries and sorts it actually performs, and makes those statistics available to you. There are queries you can run that tell you exactly what indexes Sql Server thinks it could use. I would deploy without any sorting index and let it run for a week or two that way. Then look at data and see what users actually sort on and index just those columns.

Take a look at this link for an example and introduction on finding missing indexes:
http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Find_Missing_Indexes

Comment: Thanks for the link. Quite interesting video. Although it poses more questions than it answers ... I wish it was easier to "streamline" these SQL Server databases...

Answer (score 0):

Generally indexes use to accelerate `WHERE` conditions (in some cases `JOINS`). so I don't thinks create index on column except `PRIMARY KEY` accelerate sorting. you can do your sorting in clients(if you use win forms or wpf) or in database for web scenarios

Good Luck

Comment: I use ASP.NET, but how would I sort it in clients? I have to sort the entire table even if I output only 100 pages... right?

Comment: It is not good idea to pass all of your data to clients.you should use dynamic paging so you have for example `Next` and `Back` and when user clicks on a button you can show to him appropriate data with proper sort

Comment: I don't think this statement is very accurate - since the index does already sort the data by the columns in it, it can indeed help with sorting, too! But it still doesn't make sense to just index every column....

Comment: Dear @marc_s if `PK` exist in table data sort by `PK`.

Comment: @kerezo: no, this is **NOT TRUE**. What defines the physical sort order is the **clustered index** - **NOT** the PK! Now, most often, the PK is also the clustered index - but it doesn't have to be! And even then - if you have an index on a column that's used in a `ORDER BY` clause, this can help speed up the query - since the data in the nonclustered index is already sorted by that column

Comment: @Kerezo just to clarify, I do not pass all my data to clients. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @ahmd0 However, this process will be heavy. you should do this in server side and when user want sorting you do that.Consider this important point that if you want to pass all data to client `Non-Clustered index` not matter but you should have a `Clustered index` .